# Generic string comparison with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

If you have multiple numpy arrays of different string types, such as:

```
In [411]: x1.dtype
Out[411]: dtype('S3')

In [412]: x2.dtype
Out[412]: dtype('<U3')

In [413]: x3.dtype
Out[413]: dtype('>U5')
```

Is there any way that I can check whether they are *all* strings without having to compare with each individual type explicitly?

For example, I would like to do

```
In [415]: x1.dtype == <something>
Out[415]: True

In [416]: x2.dtype == <something> # same as above
Out[416]: True

In [417]: x3.dtype == <something> # same as above
Out[417]: True
```

Comparing to `str` = no bueno:

```
In [410]: x3.dtype == str
Out[410]: False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to use [`np.issubdtype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.issubdtype.html) with [`np.character`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html#scalars):

```
np.issubdtype(your_array.dtype, np.character)
```

For example:

```
>>> np.issubdtype('S3', np.character)
True

>>> np.issubdtype('<U3', np.character)
True

>>> np.issubdtype('>U5', np.character)
True
```

This is the NumPy dtype hierarchy (as image!) taken from the NumPy documentation. It's very helpful if you want to check for common dtype classes:

[image]

As you can see `np.str_` and `np.unicode_` both "subclass" `np.character`.

Comment: This is definitely what I needed. Thanks.